# Solve the following system of equations - (5).

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

> Solve the following system of equations $$\large \left\{ \begin{align} (x + y)^2 + x^2y + 7x + 4 &= x^3 + 7y\\ 3x^2 + y^2 + 8y + 4 &= 8x \end{align}\right.$$

Here's what I did. (Sincerely, I feel very unintelligent inside.)

From the system of equations, we have that $$\left\{ \begin{align} x^3 - x^2y - x^2 - y^2 - 2xy - 8(x - y) + x - y - 4 &= 0\\ 3x^2 + y^2 + 4 = 8(x - y)\end{align} \right.$$

$\implies x^3 - x^2y - 4x^2 - 2y^2 - 2xy + x - y - 8 = 0$

$\iff x^2(x - y - 4) - (2y - 1)(x - y) - 4y^2 - 8 = 0$

And I gave up, already. Such laziness is coming out of this particular brain.

Comment: For the version $(4)$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205739/solve-the-following-system-of-equations-4). How many versions are you going to ask here?

Comment: Where can we find your other Systems?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner See under "related questions" on the right margin. It has $(1),(2),(3),(4)$.

Comment: Hm all Systems are solved

Comment: I will post a new one soon. Just wait for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Computing equation one minus equation two and factorizing we get
$$(x+5)(x-3)(x-y)=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Okay, I am stupid.

Comment: Why should you be stupid?

Comment: It is not immediately the first approach that I thought that I should tackle. There're also a lot of things I am stupid at. There're a lot more people who are better than me at one or more skills/aspects.